# Separating Apple IDs

Tags: ios, apple-id, game-center

I linked my son's iPad mini to my Apple ID. The problem is that we both play the same games and I can no longer access mine as his ID is logged into Game Center. How do I create a separate Apple ID for him on his account without affecting my iPad and accounts and get a separate Game Center account for him?

Answer (score 3):

Fill out the form to create an Apple ID using his information: https://appleid.apple.com/account
He will then start using his own ID and probably lose his old history, or you could get a new ID. Someone must start fresh I believe.